# TextBox value from a form and display it to Crystal Reports using VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameters, crystal-reports

I created a parameter in Crystal Report named `IID`. But when the report loads it has nothing to display with.

This is my code :

```
Dim cryRpt As New rptPrntIss
cryRpt.Load("C:\Users\IEEC\Desktop\Sys\InventorySys\InventorySys\rptPrntIss.rpt")
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = frmInvntStocks.txtIID.Text
crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("IID")
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
crParameterValues.Clear()
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the report object to viewer and refreshing at two places. Assign the report object (`cryRpt`) to viewer (`CrystalReportViewer1`) only in the last and remove refresh in the last too. Refresh is likely to drop all your modifications to the report object i.e. any filters, parameters etc. Modify your code as below:

```vb
cryRpt.Load("C:\Users\IEEC\Desktop\Sys\InventorySys\InventorySys\rptPrntIss.rpt")
'REMOVE REPORTSOURCE AND REFRESH STATEMENTS HERE
Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
```

and

```vb
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
'REMOVE REFRESH HERE
```

Comment: I'd follow  your advise. . but   it has the same output... nothing to display in Crystal .

Answer (score 0):

**Report Part**
Create A New Parameter 'TestParameter' on your report then put Your desire location.

**VB.Net Part**
now Click on Project Menu and go Your Project Propertise and click Setting then setup this format

[image: Y]
`Private Sub btnShowReport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowReport.Click
        Dim MyReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = New DailyShadeCosting
        MyReport.SetParameterValue("TestParameter", TextBox6.Text)
        ShowReport(MyReport, filterstring, CrystalReportViewer1)
    End Sub
   Public Sub ShowReport(ByVal MyReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument, ByVal filterstring As String, ByVal CrystalReportViewer As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer)
        Dim myLogonInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        Dim myTable As Table
        For Each myTable In MyReport.Database.Tables
            myLogonInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo
            myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = My.Settings.RptserverPath.ToString
            myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = My.Settings.Database.ToString
            myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = My.Settings.DBUser.ToString
            myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = My.Settings.DBPass.ToString
            myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myLogonInfo)
        Next myTable
        CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = MyReport
        CrystalReportViewer.SelectionFormula = filterstring
        CrystalReportViewer.Refresh()
    End Sub`